# How to launch a Docker container in Gitlab CI/CD

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, gitlab, amazon-dynamodb

I'm new to Gitlab (and I only know the basic features of git : pull, push, merge, branch...).

I'm using a local DynamoDB database launched with `docker run -p 8000:8000 amazon/dynamodb-local` to do unit testing on my Python project. So I have to launch this docker container in the Gitlab CI/CD so that my unit tests work.

I already read the documentation on this subject on the site of gitlab without finding an answer to my problem and I know that I have to modify my `gitlab-ci.yml` file in order to launch the docker container.

Comment: Docker-in-Docker is what you are looking for https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-in-docker-workflow-with-docker-executor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Gitlab you can use Docker-in-Docker.

At the top of your .gitlab-ci.yml file

```
image: docker:stable

services:
- docker:dind
```

Then in your stage for tests, you can start up the database and use it.

```
unit_tests:
  stage: tests
  script:
  - export CONTAINER_ID=$(docker run -p 8000:8000 amazon/dynamodb-local)
  ## You might need to wait a few seconds with `sleep X` for the container to start up.
  ## Your database is now here docker:8000
  ## Run your tests here. Database host=docker and port=8000
```

This is the best way I have found to achieve it and the easiest to understand

Comment: That's working, but how do I execute tests aftewards? In my particular case, I need to execute tests with maven (and tests are using a local dynamodb), but the image `docker:stable` does not contain maven, therefore `/bin/sh: eval: line 87: mvn: not found` fails on the pipeline. How to solve it?